# Incremental refresh with date as number in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to add an incremental refresh to our OrderHeader table.
This table is based on oracle and has as date as a number in the format 'CYYDDD'.
For Instance, the 01.01.2020 is in this format converted as '120001'.
That means that I have to convert this date format into a regular date/time format, to operate an incremental refresh in Power BI, right?
For now I have used this function to convert the number into a date:

```
#date(1900+Number.IntegerDivide([Date], 1000),1,1)+#duration(Number.Mod([Date], 1000)-1,0,0,0)
```

But since this function will break the query folding, there is no chance for an incremental refresh, right?
Does someone have any ideas, tips or any approach?

Comment: Can you get this date column from the source in the desired format (directly from oracle database )?

Comment: @msta42a: Unfortunately, not